# Check the Type of an entire Collection in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, classcastexception

I am writing a method `removeAll` for an `ArrayList`. By the interface, `removeAll` takes a `Collection<?>`, however, for whatever reason, I want the `Collection` to be of only `String`s. Is there any way to do this for the entire `Collection` at once?

(I am not talking about going through each element individually, like this:

```
for (Object el : c) {
    if (!(el instanceof String)) {
        throw new ClassCastException(String.format("Object %s is not of type String.", el.toString()));
    }
}
```

That is my backup, but I'd rather check the entire `Collection` at once if it's possible.)

I did try:

```
public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
    return subMethod((Collection<? extends String>) c, true); //true is unimportant here
}
```

but that just casts any `Collection<Wrapper of Primitive>` to a `Collection<String>`.

Edit: To be clear, I would like some other way to ensure the `Collection` only contains `String`s.

Comment: Given a `Collection<?>`, there is no way to check that all of its elements are Strings at once that is more efficient than your for loop.

Comment: Somewhat relevant discussion about this: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#checkedCollection(java.util.Collection,java.lang.Class)

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to do this.

Java implements generics via erasure, so the `Collection<>` itself has no idea of what its type argument was when it was created.

The concept of a generic type being on the Collection only exists when the code is being compiled, and by implementing `List.removeAll()` you are tied to the specific signature provided by that method, which does not include the `? extends E` specification that some methods like `addAll()` provide.

Further, the interface [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) for `List.removeAll()` explicitly says (*emphasis added*):

> Throws:
> ClassCastException - if the class of an element of *this list* is incompatible with the specified collection (optional)

So to fulfill the contract of this interface, you're expected to only throw an exception if an element in *your own list* is incompatible with your specific collection type: you should not throw an exception just because an item in the passed-in argument is incompatible. That's why the method signature doesn't include a `<? extends E>` in the first place: you're supposed to allow other types to be provided in the collection, and ignore them because they're clearly not going to match any values in your List.

If you want to ensure that the given collection only includes strings, one option would be to *not implement the `List` interface*. That has obvious draw-backs, but if your implementation is special it might be worthwhile for the consumers of your implementation to acknowledge that they're using a special class with special requirements, and it can't be handed to methods that only know what to do with a generalized `List`. If you do that, you've got a lot more flexibility, including declaring `removeAll()` as taking a `Collection<String>` or even a more specific, specialized, non-generic collection type that is guaranteed to only have Strings in it.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like:

```
boolean b = c.stream().allMatch(String.class::isInstance);
if(b){
      //
 }
```

Comment: That does loop though, just via a stream. OP wanted to avoid any kind of iterations or O(n) checks.